# IFRAMES & SEO - (yet unasked scenario)

Tags: iframe, search-engine, seo

I know iframes are bad for SEO and its' main purpose is to include content from other sites into the page. But my scenario is little different:

I have a vacation search engine inside my site, and this engine appears on all pages in the same position on page. The engine's code is very heavy (long) and dirty.

I thought of using iframes from 3 reasons:

1. The html of each page will be much cleaner - content is the main of the page and not other constant dirty code.
2. Since the same search engine is the same on all pages, the code will be 20% lighter since the search engine html will come from a static iframe.
3. I don't really need google to index the search engine code - I need them to index the results which appears outside the iframe.

Any thought on this practice and scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case an iframe could be a reasonable solution. But be sure that the content in the iframe would not be indexed by any Search Engine using a /robots.txt file denying access to the iframe connected file.

Regarding your point:

- Yes html would be cleaner.
- Yes could be true, you can also use
  include function on your server or Web User Controls in Asp.net.
- In this case the result page should be linked outside the iframe
  page, maybe with a page that collection the most search terms and the
  corresponding results.